# JQuery animate left and scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I need to scale and animate div left same time.

Something like this.

```
$('#div').effect('scale'{percent:200},
'animate',{left:200});
```

Thanks.

This is the solution I found.

```
 $('#div').effect('scale'{percent:200},1000);
 $('#div').animate({left:100,top:100},1000);
 $('#div').fadeTo(1100,0));
```

Comment: Obligatory what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#div').animate({
   left: 200,
   height: ($(this).height()*2),
   width: ($(this).width()*2)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I need UI scale effect.is popup thats fades scale on open

Comment: @Vahan - I don't really think you can add more effects into the effects function, it runs one effect and that's it. It also uses jQuery's animate function to do the scaling, so animating in different directions can cause strange results, have a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gWKY6/).